# How to access the parameters of objects contained within an arrayList java

Tags: java, object, arraylist, parameters, get

I am new to java programming and I am looking to build a simple text based game. I am currently trying to develop functionality that would allow a user to select a playable unit.

Here is an example of some of the code I am trying to make work now. I have pasted portions of the constructor unit class, the ranger unit class and, the beginning of the game loop class where you can see the problem. You can then see further down how i would need to replace all of my "rangerObj0.(whatever object parameter is relevant)" with some type of code that would allow me to reference potentially different objects and access their parameters. The only reason I'm using an ArrayList is because I thought this would be a simple way to "make" my own object variable that I could later reference. I am trying to access an objects parameters like this but it does not work.

```
playerChar.get(0).unitMoves
```

If there is something im missing here or a better way to do this, I'm sure there is, please advise. Thank you for you time and help!

I have spent a lot of time researching this online and I either don't know the right terminology to search for or I simply am not thinking about some functionality I have already learned. In any case I feel I am out of options to make this work on my own so I have posted here.

unit constructor class

```
public abstract class Unit {    

// instance fields
    String unitName;
    int unitHealth;
    int unitMoves;
    int unitDmg;

// constructor method
    protected Unit(String name, int health, int dmg, int moves) {
    unitName = name;
    unitHealth = health;
    unitDmg = dmg;
    unitMoves = moves;
    }

}
```

Ranger unit class

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Ranger extends Unit{ 

public Ranger(String name, int health, int dmg, int moves) {
    super(name, health, dmg, moves);    
}
```

Game loop class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Game {

public static void main(String[] args) {

boolean gameLoop = true;
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
int player;

Ranger rangerObj0 = new Ranger("Ranger", 100, 10, 4);
Heavy heavyObj0 = new Heavy("Ranger", 100, 20, 4);
Monster monsterObj0 = new Monster("Steel Head", 150, 10, 3);

//Start of game ----------------------------------------------------------

System.out.println("Select you character!");
System.out.println("Enter 1 for Ranger(100, 10, 4)");
System.out.println("Enter 2 for Heavy (100, 20, 4)");
int resp = keyboard.nextInt();
```

here is the ArrayList and related if statement I am trying to use which comes immediately after the preceding code

```
ArrayList<Object> playerChar = new ArrayList<Object>();

if (resp == 1){
  playerChar.add(rangerObj0);
} else if (resp == 2) {
  playerChar.add(heavyObj0);
} else {
  System.out.println("Please enter a valid responce!");
}
```

The commented section below is left in to show where the game loop begins

Here you can see the first instance of me trying to reference the objects parameters via the .get() method

```
/*while(gameLoop == true) { 
playerChar.get(0).unitMoves = 4; /* <--------- */
monsterObj0.unitMoves = 3;
boolean endPlayerTurn = false; */

while (endPlayerTurn == false) { 
  System.out.println("Your "+rangerObj0.unitName+" is ready to fight! What do you want to do?");
  System.out.println("Enter 1 to rappid fire for 2 movment points");
  System.out.println("Enter 2 to pistol fire for 1 movment point");
  System.out.println("Enter 3 to end turn");
  resp = keyboard.nextInt(); 
  if (resp == 1) { 
    rangerObj0.rapidFire(monsterObj0);
  } else if (resp == 2) { 
    rangerObj0.rapidFire(monsterObj0);
  } else if (resp == 3) { 
    System.out.println("Player turn ended!");
    endPlayerTurn = true;
  } else if (rangerObj0.unitMoves == 0) { 
    System.out.println(rangerObj0.unitName +" is out of moves! Do you want to end turn by typing 3?");
  } else { 
    System.out.println("please enter a valid response!");
  } 
} 
//End of player turn -----------------------------------------------------
```

The NPC turn would come next and then the conclusion or repeat of the game loop.

Here is the error I get wen trying to reference an objects parameters via the .get() method as seen in the game loop section of the code that I pointed out above

"unitMoves cannot be resolved or is not a valid field"

Comment: Your list is an `ArrayList<Object>`. Object doesn't have any `unitMoves` attribute. If you want a list of units, create an `ArrayList<Unit>`, not an `ArrayList<Object>`.

Comment: can you think of a better way in general for me to do this? I'm now having trouble accessing methods contained in each of these classes.

Comment: Have you read my comment? It does explain a better way.

Comment: I have but I am now running into this error playerChar.get(0).rapidFire(monsterObj0); This line of code does not work because I cant access the methods contained within the Ranger class. I'm now trying to work around this with multiple ArrayLists being stored in one array list but I am having trouble as each ArrayList is different Monster, Ranger, and Heavy.

Comment: Your answer was spot on but, i think the type of functionality I'm actually trying to achieve here should not be done in the way that I'm trying to do it. I just couldn't think of any other way to reference an object later in my code like I might reference the stored value of a variable. Basically what I want to do is have a player select a class, Ranger or Heavy, and use that class's methods and object parameters throughout my code.

Comment: Ideally, all the methods you want to call on a Unit should be declared in Unit, and overridden by subclasses. If that is not possible, you'll have to check what the type of the Unit is, and cast it to a Ranger if it is a Ranger.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to make this work with ArrayList with the generic type Object. If you write the following code:

```
Object currentUnit = playerChar.get(0);
if (currentUnit instanceof Ranger) {
 Ranger ranger = (Ranger) currentUnit;
 //do what a Ranger should do...
} else if (currentUnit instanceof Heavy) {
 Heavy heavy = (Heavy) currentUnit;
 //do what a Monster should do...
} else {
 Monster monster = (Monster) currentUnit;
 //do what a Monster should do...
}
```

, then this should work.